# Debian : 2 Nic 2 different networks switches - kernel sees a bad network

Tags: linux, debian, networking, routing

Hello

Here is the situation :

- VMplayer with 2 physical NICs (network interface cards) on the Windows host

- VM Debian 64bits

- On VM settings: both NICs are configured to replicate on the physical network

- When VM Debian is running, I declared 2 NICs :


ETH0 : 0.0.0.0 (dedicated to snort)

ETH1 : 172.22.0.12 set on dhcp (internet)


ETH0 is up and in promiscuous mode to receive mirroring flow from a switch

ETH1 is using to go to internet


I have some update scripts that must download some data from internet.

They cannot access the network, even if `/etc/resolv.conf` is well configured.


Depending tests that I did :

Or I can go to the net, but no capture on snort that listens eth0 

Or I cannot go to the internet and snort capture eth0 


What is(are) the configuration you think ?


I wish :


ETH0 : 0.0.0.0 : capture the traffic that arriving 

ETH1 : dhcp : go to the internet from kernel (root) login for my scripts 


Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the default route is via the eth1 interface.  For example:

```
route del default
route add default eth1
```

That will delete the existing default route (if any) and add a new default route via eth1.

You could add those as `post-up` commands to the definition of `eth1` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  e.g.

```
iface eth1 inet dhcp
post-up route del default || true
post-up route add default eth1
```

The `|| true` ensures that the `route del default` never returns a failure exit code, even if there is no default route to delete.  Without that, `ifup` could abort before running the `route add default eth1` command.

Answer (score -1):

The problem came because VMPlayer needs to have a bridge nic and a nat bridge. After this, linux configuration interfaces are as usual.